# Swing Java txt file writing to JTextArea

Tags: java, bufferedreader, jtextarea

Is there a way to make the null go away at the end of the file? I decided to append the first line before the while loop so it wouldn't be affected by the \n but in doing so the null appears... (without the first append it just skips the first line and starts printing on the second line)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class notepadMinus implements ActionListener{
    //Properties
    JFrame theFrame;
    JPanel thePanel;
    JMenuBar theBar;
    JMenu theMenu;
    JMenuItem openItem;
    JMenuItem saveItem;
    JTextArea theArea;
    JScrollPane theScroll;
    JFileChooser openChoose;
    String strLine;
    //Methods
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        if(evt.getSource() == openItem){
            System.out.println("Open File");
            int intResult = openChoose.showOpenDialog(openItem);
            if(intResult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                System.out.println("File selected");
                File selectedFile = openChoose.getSelectedFile();
                theArea.selectAll();
                theArea.replaceSelection("");
                try{
                    BufferedReader txtfile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(openChoose.getSelectedFile()));
                    strLine = txtfile.readLine();
                    theArea.append(strLine);
                    while(strLine != null){
                        strLine = txtfile.readLine();
                        theArea.append( "\n" +  strLine);   
                    }
                    txtfile.close();
                }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                    System.out.println("File Not Found");
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("Reading Error");
                }   
                //read lines
                //put those lines in theArea - append
                //System.out.println(openChoose.getSelectedFile());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Cancelled?");
            }
        }
    }
    //Constructor
    notepadMinus(){
        theFrame = new JFrame("Notepad Minus");
        theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        thePanel = new JPanel();
        thePanel.setLayout(null);
        thePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        
        theBar = new JMenuBar();
        //theBar.setSize(600,50);
        //theBar.setLocation(100, 50);
        //thePanel.add(theBar);
        theFrame.setJMenuBar(theBar);
        
        theMenu = new JMenu("File");
        theBar.add(theMenu);
        
        openItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
        openItem.addActionListener(this);
        theMenu.add(openItem);
        
        saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
        saveItem.addActionListener(this);
        theMenu.add(saveItem);
        
        theArea = new JTextArea();
        theScroll = new JScrollPane(theArea);
        theScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        
        //theFrame.setContentPane(thePanel);
        theFrame.setContentPane(theScroll);
        theFrame.pack();
        theFrame.setVisible(true);
        
        openChoose = new JFileChooser();
        
    }
    //Main Method
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new notepadMinus();
    }
}
```

What it looks like in the JTextArea

```
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
null
```

Answer (score 0):

## The solution

Change

```java
theArea.append(strLine);
while(strLine != null){
    strLine = txtfile.readLine();
    theArea.append( strLine + "\n" );   
}
```

to

```java
while(strLine != null){
    theArea.append( "\n" +  strLine);   
    strLine = txtfile.readLine();
}
```

## The mistake

By reading just before printing, you are skipping the null check.
You are already reading a line from `txtfile` before the loop. You should print it first before you read another.
There is another consequence of this mistake - the first line is skipped.
If your file had

```
a
b
c
d
```

as its contents, the output would be

```
b
c
d
null
```

Comment: changing that does remove the null at the end but now theres an extra line printed out resulting: a
a
b
c
d
e

Comment: @Jack Just remove the line `theArea.append(strLine);`.

Comment: Yes, but now there is a space on the first line due to the \n "(blank) a b c d e"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! the `\n` should be after `strLine`:

```
while(strLine != null){
    theArea.append(strLine + "\n");   
    strLine = txtfile.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or make it a lot easier with

```
theArea.read(txtFile, ""); // Done so just your close code now
```